# PicketLink: 'ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00' when setting passwords

Tags: postgresql, jpa, picketlink

I have a Java EE app configured to use PicketLink as its security framework.  The app is running on JBoss EAP 7 (or Wildfly 10), and is using PostgreSQL 9.4 as its backend datastore.  I'm initializing the PicketLink IDM framework to use PBKDF2 password encoding like so:

```
builder.named("MyApp").stores().jpa()
        .setCredentialHandlerProperty(PasswordCredentialHandler.PASSWORD_ENCODER,
                new PBKDF2PasswordEncoder("salty".getBytes(), 10000, 128))
        .addContextInitializer(new PicketLinkContextInitializer(this.entityManager));
```

With this configuration, however, I periodically get the following Exception when trying to set a password:

```
Caused by: org.picketlink.idm.IdentityManagementException: PLIDM000201: Credential update failed for account [net.odyssi.identity.security.model.ExtendedUser@ac8b3d20] and type [org.picketlink.idm.credential.Password@17321a51].
    at org.picketlink.idm.internal.ContextualIdentityManager.updateCredential(ContextualIdentityManager.java:235) [picketlink-idm-impl-2.7.0.Final.jar:]
    at org.picketlink.idm.internal.ContextualIdentityManager.updateCredential(ContextualIdentityManager.java:217) [picketlink-idm-impl-2.7.0.Final.jar:]
    at net.odyssi.identity.services.security.CredentialManager.changeAccountPassword(CredentialManager.java:75) [IdentityPlatform-ejb-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    ... 175 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692) [hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.9.Final-redhat-1.jar:5.0.9.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602) [hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.9.Final-redhat-1.jar:5.0.9.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608) [hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.9.Final-redhat-1.jar:5.0.9.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1303) [hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.9.Final-redhat-1.jar:5.0.9.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.flush(AbstractEntityManager.java:459) [wildfly-jpa-7.0.0.GA-redhat-2.jar:7.0.0.GA-redhat-2]
    at org.picketlink.idm.jpa.internal.JPAIdentityStore.storeCredential(JPAIdentityStore.java:912) [picketlink-idm-impl-2.7.0.Final.jar:]
    at org.picketlink.idm.credential.handler.AbstractCredentialHandler.update(AbstractCredentialHandler.java:225) [picketlink-idm-api-2.7.0.Final.jar:]
    at org.picketlink.idm.credential.handler.AbstractCredentialHandler.update(AbstractCredentialHandler.java:51) [picketlink-idm-api-2.7.0.Final.jar:]
    at org.picketlink.idm.internal.AbstractIdentityStore.updateCredential(AbstractIdentityStore.java:145) [picketlink-idm-impl-2.7.0.Final.jar:]
    at org.picketlink.idm.internal.ContextualIdentityManager.updateCredential(ContextualIdentityManager.java:231) [picketlink-idm-impl-2.7.0.Final.jar:]
    ... 177 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:118) [hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final-redhat-1.jar:5.0.9.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) [hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final-redhat-1.jar:5.0.9.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) [hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final-redhat-1.jar:5.0.9.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95) [hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final-redhat-1.jar:5.0.9.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207) [hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final-redhat-1.jar:5.0.9.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45) [hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final-redhat-1.jar:5.0.9.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2886) [hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final-redhat-1.jar:5.0.9.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3386) [hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final-redhat-1.jar:5.0.9.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89) [hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final-redhat-1.jar:5.0.9.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:560) [hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final-redhat-1.jar:5.0.9.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:434) [hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final-redhat-1.jar:5.0.9.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337) [hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final-redhat-1.jar:5.0.9.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) [hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final-redhat-1.jar:5.0.9.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282) [hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final-redhat-1.jar:5.0.9.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1300) [hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.9.Final-redhat-1.jar:5.0.9.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 183 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2198)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1927)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:561)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:419)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:365)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:537)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204) [hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final-redhat-1.jar:5.0.9.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 193 more
```

I say periodically, because the error does not appear to occur every single time.  I can set small numbers of passwords (<5) with no problem.  However, if I try to create user accounts in bulk, the error happens every time.  I also see it crop up occasionally, regardless of how many accounts I am creating.

Any idea why this error is occurring or how I can correct it?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to store a zero byte in a table column with a string data type, which is not allowed in PostgreSQL.

Use the PostgreSQL data type `bytea` instead which can be used to store arbitrary binary data.

Comment: Yes, I realize that.  My question was more about PicketLink and why it's doing it/how I could work around it.

Comment: Did PicketLink create the table? If yes, you'd have to take the issue up with them.